# How do I make a redirect with the condition referer and user_agent in Nginx?

Tags: nginx

Tell me please
How do I make a redirect with the condition referer and user_agent?
I now have the "valid_referers"
valid_referers sub.test.com;

```
if ($invalid_referer) {
   return 301 https://test.com;
}
```

Can I make a condition that "if the invalid referrer and user_agent are not safari, then redirect"?
We must exclude Safari if the referrer is invalid.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
map $http_user_agent $notsafari {
    ~Safari/    "";
    default     "1";
}

server {
    ...
    if ("$invalid_referer$notsafari" = "11") {
        return 301 https://test.com;
    }
    ...
```

Note that the `map` substitution should be declared **outside** the `server` block.